Microsoft Root Program - Signatures using elliptical curve cryptography (ECC) are not supported in Windows - What does it mean?
Can someone explain the note in Microsoft Root Program (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/program-requirements):

B. Signature Requirements
Expand table
Algorithm   All Uses Except for Code Signing and Time Stamping  Code Signing and Time Stamping Use
Digest Algorithms   SHA2 (SHA256, SHA384, SHA512)   SHA2 (SHA256, SHA384, SHA512)
RSA 2048    4096 (New roots only)
ECC / ECDSA NIST P-256, P-384, P-521    NIST P-256, P-384, P-521
Please Note: Signatures using elliptical curve cryptography (ECC), such as ECDSA, are not supported in Windows and newer Windows security features. Users utilizing these algorithms and certificates will face various errors and potential security risks. The Microsoft Trusted Root Program recommends that ECC/ECDSA certificates should not be issued to subscribers due to this known incompatibility and risk.

I search over internet and found no explanation.
I see that .NET supports ECC signatures...
I see that Microsoft Root Program has no issue with ECC based certificates.
What could mean that note or where I could find the answer ?

I think that's for Code Signing, and means that the certificates used for that purpose must be of the RSA type. No Elliptic Curve. It seems that some Windows stuff doesn't fully support ECC certs. I readed that people using ECC certs for Code Signing were still getting the infamous SmartScreen warning.
